# Search bar not populating from github

Tags: reactjs, github, react-redux, axios, github-api

I am new to react and I am following a tutorial in react js to populate my page with profile ids on clicking the search button on form submit. I am using axios for communicating with github apis. However I am not able to populate my page with the user ids. I do not know much about the github api . I think there might be a problem with my query. I am using a personal token. to generate requests.

Here is my screen on clicking the search button:

[image]

It should look something like this:
[image]

Here is my app.js code where I am trying to fetch the request:

```
const github = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.github.com",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: { Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN },
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  

  searchUsers = async (text) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await github.get(`/search/users?q=${text}`);

    this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />

        <div className="conatiner">
          <Search searchUsers={this.searchUsers} />
          <Users loading={this.state.loading} users={this.state.users} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is my search.js code where I am using onFormSubmit to process what happens on submit:

```
export class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text:""});
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="Search Users...."
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

The token I use Here in .env.local file in my root folder:

REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN='token '

Please help. I do not know what is wrong

Comment: I can't reproduce, works for me. Can you also share your `Users` component? Also log the response to see if the problem is not getting the data or the way you're displaying the data.

Comment: The problem is probably in the `Users` component, because https://api.github.com/search/users?q=brad works fine even without an access token.

Comment: It worked I dont know I made no changes to the code it started working the next day. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Maybe you were rate limited. There is a limited amount of requests you are allowed to send per hour. https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/rate-limits-for-github-apps#server-to-server-requests. But this is just a guess, it could've been something else, hard to say.